# What is 'Dark Soil' for?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Throughout the isle of Pandaria I have noticed that there are lootable piles of 'Dark Soil':

[image: Dark Soil]

These contain one of several items, including;

- Marsh Lilly
- Lovely Apple
- Ruby Shard

What are these items and what can I do with them?

Comment: Are these "dark soil" patches in all of the zones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These items can be given to members of the Tiller faction, in exchange for friendship. You do not gain reputation with the Tiller faction itself, but each member of the Tillers has a friendship level:

[image]

Each item you can pick up will give you reputation, but you can get additional reputation by giving the item to the named person in the description of each item as follows;

- Blue Feather - Old Hillpaw or Chee Chee
- Jade Cat - Fish Fellreed or Ella
- Lovely Apple - Sho or Jogu the Drunk
- Marsh Lilly - Farmer Fung or Gina Mudclaw
- Ruby Shard - Tina Mudclaw or Haohan Mudclaw

By giving the item to the person named in the description, you will gain 900 reputation with that individual, if you give an item to a person not named in the description you will receive 540 reputation with that person.

Each person has additional quests for you once you reach certain levels of friendship with them and will give you a vanity item for your farm once you become best friends with them.